# Is it possible to use reserved words for field names?

Tags: delphi

For compatibility reasons (objects are serialized and exported and must match external names) I would like to have a field name being 'type', i.e.

```
TTBaseWebResponse = class
private
   type: String;
   success: Integer;       
end;

or

TTBaseWebResponse = class
private
   ftype: String;
   fsuccess: Integer;       
public
   type: string read fstring write fstring;
   success: integer read fsuccess write fsuccess;   
end;
```

Delphi (XE2) won't even compile this. 
Is this at all possible? How?

Comment: Only if you [`use & char before its name`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6063439/960757)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using & before the field name

Comment: The magic of this is that the RTTI seems to know this field as 'type' (without the ampersand) 'all the way down'. I'm using SuperObjects' TSuperRttiContext for serializing the object and the JSON output is: {"success":1,"type":"TTBaseWebResponse"} without the ampersand - just like I want it.

Comment: That's because its name *is* `type` without the ampersand. The ampersand is simply an escape character for the parser. When not parsing, you don't need to escape anything. When referencing the field elsewhere in your code, you can avoid the ampersand by fully qualifying the name. For example, `Response.type`.

Answer (score 8):

This is covered by the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Extended_Identifiers):

> **Extended Identifiers**
>
> You might encounter identifiers (e.g. types, or methods in a class)
>   having the same name as a Delphi language reserved word. For example,
>   a class might have a method called `begin`. Delphi reserved words such
>   as **begin** cannot be used for an identifier name.
>
> If you fully qualify the identifier, then there is no problem. For
>   example, if you want to use the Delphi reserved word **type** for an
>   identifer name, you must use its fully qualified name:
>
> ```
> var TMyType.type
> // Using a fully qualified name avoids ambiguity with Delphi language keyword.
> ```
>
> As a shorter alternative, the ampersand (**&**) operator can be used
>   to resolve ambiguities between identifiers and Delphi language
>   reserved words. The **&** prevents a keyword from being parsed as a
>   keyword (that is, a reserved word). If you encounter a method or type
>   that is the same name as a Delphi keyword, you can omit the namespace
>   specification if you prefix the identifier name with an ampersand. But
>   when you are **declaring** an identifier that has the same name as a
>   keyword, you *must* use the **&**:
>
> ```
> type
>   &Type = Integer; 
>   // Prefix with '&' is ok.
> ```

Comment: It seems that this can not be used in Delphi 7 ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you must use & before name;

```
TTBaseWebResponse = class
private
  &type: String;
  success: Integer;       
end;
```